# Is there a way to reset the ID of a List inside a SharePoint Server 2007 (MOSS)?

Tags: list

After testing my list with a complex workflow on my MOSS 2007 production server, the ID have reach 100. Is it possible to reset the ID to the original value that it was created?

(Otherwise, I have to recreate my list which contain 65 columns again.)

Comment: I would advise against testing on your production server, do you have a test environment to do testing?

Comment: Our company does not have a test environment and also, we do not want to export from test environment to production if we have a test environment as it will increase the work load.

Comment: It is a good idea to have another environment somewhere, to test upgrades etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no you can't reset it.

The only way is to delete and recreate the list. 
You can save the list as a template (not including content), then recreate it from the list template. 
This would recreate the list without you having to re-add the columns. :)

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response! Thanks for the recommendation on saving it as a template.

Comment: Is the workflow deployed (custom) or ootb? Be careful with the workflow when recreating the list as a template: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/57f044b0-279c-459c-8a15-f8fb45c4d688/